# How to use primitive restart function

Tags: opengl

I am trying to make terrain mesh, and for now got something like this:

```
    GL.PushMatrix();
    GL.Begin(BeginMode.TriangleStrip);

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            GL.Vertex2(0 + 50 * j, 0 + 50 * i);
            GL.Vertex2(0 + 50 * j, 0 + 50 + 50 * i);
        }

    }

    GL.End();
    GL.PopMatrix();
```

But it doesn't look like supposed, how should it be done properly?

[image http://img821.imageshack.us/img821/5387/otkl.jpg](http://img821.imageshack.us/img821/5387/otkl.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to draw the entire terrain as a single triangle strip, you need to use "degenerate triangles" (triangles that have two or three vertices at same position) and draw even and odd rows in different directions. [Here](http://www.chadvernon.com/blog/resources/directx9/terrain-generation-with-a-heightmap/)'s one tutorial about it, although for DirectX, but the loops for positioning the vertices should be pretty much the same.

Comment: So it is impossible to decrease amount of vertices? they need to be doubled? What about programs like Blender, which can merge many vertices together, how they do it?

Comment: With a single triangle strip, I'd say so. You should probably look into indexed vertex arrays/OpenGL's Vertex Buffer Objects (VBOs), with those you can declare each vertex of the grid just once and then use indices to map the triangles. It's been quite a while since the last time I've used OpenGL, but there are loads of tutorials floating around the 'net.

Comment: Recent versions of OpenGL provides primitive restart: A special index is reserved for starting a new strip.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot use primitive restart without an index list. Also, primitive restart is a performance enhancing tool; if you're using immediate mode rendering (`glBegin/End`), you've already given up on performance. So just put the begin and end within the loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    GL.Begin(BeginMode.TriangleStrip);
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    {
        GL.Vertex2(0 + 50 * j, 0 + 50 * i);
        GL.Vertex2(0 + 50 * j, 0 + 50 + 50 * i);
    }
    GL.End();
}
```